# Mathematical Logic: Translate into predicate calculus notation.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, logic-translation

Translate into predicate calculus notation:

***That, that that is, is not that, that that is not.***

Is my translation to mathematical logic correct? Thank you for your help!

My explanation: one example would be using the same structure

***Love, which love is, is not love, which love is not.***

Converting it to logic,

(x) [(Lx is equivalent to Lx) is equivalent to (not Lx is equivalent to not Lx)]

Coming back from love to that, my answer is:

***(x) [(Tx is equivalent to Tx) is equivalent to (not Tx is equivalent to not Tx)]***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your punctuation is correct, but I would symbolize it quite differently:

$\forall x \forall y (x=y \rightarrow \neg x \not = y)$

In short, whatever something is, is not what it is not.

Comment: Thank you for fast and helpful comment! I am also thinking if two variables are needed! One new question. As the equal symbol that you are using does not exist in Logic, would you agree that instead of equal to use the equivalent symbol? I have seen that the not equivalent symbol exists in Latex, but not for logic. How to change your not equal? Maybe not x is equivalent to not y?

Comment: The $=$ symbol is actually a fixed symbol of first-order logic, so you can defintitely use it! And $x \not = y$ is shorthand for $\neg x = y$. So, the second part of my sentence would really become $\neg \neg x = y$ .... But I thought it was clearer using the $\not =$

Comment: One question about your last comment. You wrote $\neg x \not = y)$, and you told me that really would be $\neg\neg x  = y)$ Would be better $\neg x  = \neg y)$? Yes? No? Why?

Comment: @Beginner No!  $\neg x = \neg y$ is not a statement! The identity should be between objects, and $\neg x$ nor $\neg y$  is not an object ... in fact, it isn't a meaningful (or grammatical) logic string at all. When I write $\neg x = y$, I don't mean $(\neg x) = y$, but $\neg (x = y)$

Comment: I am talking about $\forall x \forall y (x=y \rightarrow \neg x  = \neg y)$

Comment: @Beginner No, that's just not a meaningful or grammatical expression.

Comment: May you explain me why?

Comment: I am thinking that my idea would be false if we analyze not dog = not cat. Is that the problem?

Comment: No, that's not it. It's that 'not cat' isn't anything you can use in logic. It's not an object, nor is it a claim.

Comment: @Beginner No problem!  This is a common mistake!

Comment: Would be wrong to change x and y for Wx and Wy. Using Wx for whatever x is and Wy for whatever y is? Sorry for keep asking about this problem...

Comment: @Beginner sorry, but no, that doesn't work either: Wx would need to be a predicate and thus be a claim about x. 'Whatever x is' is not a predicate nor a claim.

Comment: I am again thinking about this logic problem and I have a question. Does a way exist to use a function for this problem or it is totally impossible? I think that you answer was it is totally impossible, but I would like to confirm.

Comment: @Beginner But what would $f(x)$ be? The 'totality' of what x is, i.e. the whole of its properties and relationships?  I suppose you could try and do that, but it is highly unusual, and moreover, if you just want to talk about what something is, then I would just use true identity, i.e. what the '=' expresses.

Comment: Thanks again for all your teachings, your patience, and your willingness to explain any doubt. You are one of the best professors that I have met in my life!